# Encountering a problem while moving to Django 1.1

Tags: python, django-templates

I'm trying to move from django 1.0.2 to 1.1 and I am getting the following error in one of my templates:

> Request Method: GET
>
> Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/conserv/media_assets/vod/
>
> Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
>
> Exception Value:        Caught an exception while rendering:
>   'NoneType'
>
> object has no attribute 'label'
>
> Exception Location:
>   /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/
>
> Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py in
>
> render_node, line 81
>
> Python Executable:
>   /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/
>
> Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>
> Python Version: 2.6.2
>
> The error is on the line with the "for" tag.

My template:

```html
{% for field in upload_image_form %} 
        <tr> 
                <td class="label"> 
                        {{field.name}} 
                </td> 
                <td> 
                        {{field}} 
                </td> 
        </tr> 
{% endfor %}
```

My form:

```py
class UploadImageForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = ImageUpload 
        fields = ('thumb')
```

My model:

```py
class ImageUpload(models.Model): 
    thumb = models.FileField(upload_to='thumbs', blank=True, null=True)
```

Does anyone know how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's an error in your form class. The fields should be an iterable, but a tuple with one element should be written `('thumb',)` instead of `('thumb')`. Change your form class to :

```
class UploadImageForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta: 
    model = ImageUpload 
    fields = ('thumb',)
```

It should do the trick.